# What is wrong with following answers? Possible error in exercise?

Tags: verbos, modismos

I have been doing my homework on a online platform which our university provided and I came at sort of impasse.
I am supposed to form sentences from several words provided in the exercise.

When given words: se / en / español / cómo / dice / man

I wrote: *Cómo se dice man en espaňol?*

However for some reason this is not the correct answer.

Is it possible that I have missed something really obvious or is it just an error in the exercise?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few things that stick out pretty clearly that would quickly throw off an on-line system depending on how it's been configured:

```
 Cómo se dice man en espaňol?
^ need opening question mark (¿)

 Cómo se dice man en espaňol?
             ^   ^ need quotation marks or italics

 Cómo se dice man en espaňol?
                         ^ need ñ (U+00F1 or U+006E U+0303)
                           you have ň (U+0148 or U+006E U+030C)
```

In all, you should have the following:

> ¿Cómo se dice «man» en español?
>   <sup>(alternates for «man»: “man” ‘man’ "man" 'man' *man*)</sup>

Given the systems that I've used in teaching, I'd say the **ñ/ň** swap is the most likely to cause the mistake, I'd give it a 50/50 chance that the lack of **¿** caused it, and the lack of quotation marks / italics is highly unlikely to have caused it.

Also, another possibility is that the system expected some other word order.  Spanish has *much* more flexible word order than English.  With this one, there's not too many common options, but all of the following are also grammatically valid (the first one is the only really likely one that the system would have used):

- ¿Cómo se dice en español *man*?
- ¿Cómo, en español, se dice *man*?
- En español, ¿cómo se dice *man*?
- *Man* en español, ¿cómo se dice?
- En español *man* se dice ¿cómo?
- etc.

Comment: I will try the ň although thus far it had no problems with it. As  for ¿, the question marks are preset so thats probably not it. I will come back when I know for sure. And thank you very much.

Comment: @user1561358 I have updated my answer with another possibility

Comment: Yeah it was the ñ/ň. Funny thing is that thus far it didn't matter when I entered ň. Not even in this very exercise. (ň is a valid syllable in my countrys language so that why they substitute it, probably)                                 Thanks a lot, if I could give you upvote I would. :)